# SVN Switch to new repositary is not working

Tags: svn

My current repository is : **/var/www/svn/project**.all my files within project folder.it doesn't have trunk,branches,tags structure as of now.
Now i have created new project as "**/var/www/svn/projectnew**" with trunk,branches,tags.
I took the Dump of "**/var/www/svn/project**" and loaded to "**/var/www/svn/projectnew/trunck**" and created one branch in "**/var/www/svn/projectnew/branches/site1**" from trunk.

Currently my Working copy pointing "**/var/www/svn/project**". i tried to switch my working copy from "**/var/www/svn/project**" to "**/var/www/svn/projectnew/branches/site1**" but it saying,

*Repository UUID 'd3f06af7-c344-2d45-b1bd-7799e0e99d7a' doesn't match expected UID 'f5f9f6ac-3f50-7e4d-a9d4-0bc9a9b443b8'.*

Help me on how i can go with this?

Answer (score 1):

You should relocate your current working copy. Command [`svn relocate`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/c/relocate/) will help you.

Comment: SVN RELOCATE also not working - am getting the below error when i try to do svn relocate "The repositary at http://localhost/projectnew/branches/site1 has uuid 'yyyyy', but the WC has 'xxxxx'"

Comment: Does the fresh checkout work?

Comment: yes.fresh checkout is working fine. problem with working copy only.